# Spring Boot Microservices - Rest Template 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a problem about sending a request to other service from one service. All services have security. That's why you couldn't send a request to url without the bearer token.

I after getting bearer token of `ROLE_USER` from this url `localhost:9090/authenticate/login`

I defined bearer token in getOrderDetails of Order Service but I got this issue shown below. How can I fix the issue?

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 : "{ "error": "Full authentication is required to access this resource" }<EOL><EOL>"
```

Here are problem in the code snippets shown below to call another service.

```
public OrderResponse getOrderDetails(long orderId, String bearerToken) {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer "+ bearerToken);

        HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

        log.info("OrderServiceImpl | getOrderDetails | Get order details for Order Id : {}", orderId);

        Order order
                = orderRepository.findById(orderId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new CustomException("Order not found for the order Id:" + orderId,
                        "NOT_FOUND",
                        404));

        log.info("OrderServiceImpl | getOrderDetails | Invoking Product service to fetch the product for id: {}", order.getProductId());
        /*ProductResponse productResponse
                = restTemplate.getForObject(
                "http://PRODUCT-SERVICE/product/" + order.getProductId(),
                ProductResponse.class
        );*/

        // HERE IS THE ISSUE
        ResponseEntity<ProductResponse> responseProduct = restTemplate.exchange(
                "http://PRODUCT-SERVICE/product/" + order.getProductId(),
                HttpMethod.GET, request, ProductResponse.class);
        ProductResponse productResponse = responseProduct.getBody();


        log.info("OrderServiceImpl | getOrderDetails | Getting payment information form the payment Service");
        /*PaymentResponse paymentResponse
                = restTemplate.getForObject(
                "http://PAYMENT-SERVICE/payment/order/" + order.getId(),
                PaymentResponse.class
        );*/

        // HERE IS THE ISSUE
        ResponseEntity<PaymentResponse> responsePayment = restTemplate.exchange(
                "http://PAYMENT-SERVICE/payment/order/" + order.getId(),
                HttpMethod.GET, request, PaymentResponse.class);
        PaymentResponse paymentResponse = responsePayment.getBody();

        OrderResponse.ProductDetails productDetails
                = OrderResponse.ProductDetails
                .builder()
                .productName(productResponse.getProductName())
                .productId(productResponse.getProductId())
                .build();

        OrderResponse.PaymentDetails paymentDetails
                = OrderResponse.PaymentDetails
                .builder()
                .paymentId(paymentResponse.getPaymentId())
                .paymentStatus(paymentResponse.getStatus())
                .paymentDate(paymentResponse.getPaymentDate())
                .paymentMode(paymentResponse.getPaymentMode())
                .build();

        OrderResponse orderResponse
                = OrderResponse.builder()
                .orderId(order.getId())
                .orderStatus(order.getOrderStatus())
                .amount(order.getAmount())
                .orderDate(order.getOrderDate())
                .productDetails(productDetails)
                .paymentDetails(paymentDetails)
                .build();

        log.info("OrderServiceImpl | getOrderDetails | orderResponse : " + orderResponse.toString());

        return orderResponse;
    }
```

**Fixed the issue :** After removing the "Bearer" in getOrderDetails of OrderServiceImpl , It works

How can I fix the issue?

Here is the repo : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/springbootmicroservicedailybuffer)

**To run the app,**

1 ) Run Service Registery (Eureka Server)

2 ) Run config server

3 ) Run zipkin and redis through these commands shown below on docker

```
  docker run -d -p 9411:9411 openzipkin/zipkin
  docker run -d --name redis -p 6379:6379 redis
```

4 ) Run api gateway

5 ) Run other services

Comment: Can you share the whole stack trace and the relevant code in a codeblock?

Comment: @dan1st I shared it.

Comment: I think user role is problem. Can you share user roles in JwtAuthenticationFilter.java for PRODUCT-SERVICE (line 43)?

Comment: @erenerdogan ROLE_USER is responsible for `http://PRODUCT-SERVICE/product/{id}` and `http://PAYMENT-SERVICE/payment/order/{id}`. I also shared all these classes.

Comment: for(String rolename : jwtUtils.getRoleNamesFromJwtToken(jwt)){
      authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(rolename));
} let me know what is rolename for this code in JwtAuthenticationFilter.java? ROLE_USER or USER?

Comment: @erenerdogan ROLE_USER. I can send a request to `http://localhost:8081/product/1` or `http://localhost:9090/product/1` and `http://localhost:8083/payment/order/1` or `http://localhost:9090/payment/order/1` with a bearer token contaning ROLE_USER.

Comment: headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer "+ bearerToken); can you try this line without "Bearer "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer

After removing the "Bearer" in `getOrderDetails` of `OrderServiceImpl` , It works